# ion-content overlaps with ion-header when in ion-router-outlet

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

i am using the latest version of ionic4(rc0) and i am trying to create my `<ion-header>` in the app.component.ts in root.

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
          <img src="assets/atippr_logo.svg" class="atippr-header"/>
        </ion-title>

      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-menu side="start">

      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>

      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ion-item menuClose="start" href="/dashboard">
            <ion-icon name="apps" item-left></ion-icon>
            Dashboard
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-menu>

    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

and later i want to set my `<ion-content>` in my routed page.

```
<ion-content>
  Login
</ion-content>
```

but now the content of my page always overlaps with the header from app.component.ts
when i remember correctly in ionic3 there was a tag addition hasHeader="true"
but without effect.

anybody can help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if it still relevant but I had the same issue and found this structure to solve it:

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>    
      <ion-title>Header</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>     
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content >
   <ion-router-outlet >
   </ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-app>
```

Also don't forget to open a new  (with/without padding) in you components html

Comment: have you tried putting ion-segments down of the header`? this looks a bit ugly cause of the header shadow at the bottom of it

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing that as well thnx, you can also add padding though

Comment: @swforlife by adding the <ion-content> in the app.componen.html, did you then not have any <ion-content> tags on any of your pages? As the Ionic docs state there can only be one ion-content per view and having it like this adds two. I also want to implement this but just wondering if you faced any issues having two ion-content tags per view?

Comment: @Kirsten -> I have 2 ionic-content, one on app component and one on a page and I get scrolling issues on iOS when I use fixed content (I am using Ionic5 with Angular)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with @ionic/react 7

An alternative to the accepted solution is to move `IonRouterOutlet` above `IonApp`:

```html
<IonReactRouter history={history}>
  <IonRouterOutlet>
    <IonApp>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInPage} />
      </Provider>
    </IonApp>
  </IonRouterOutlet>
</IonReactRouter>
```