# ion-footer not showing when ion-content contains elements

Tags: javascript, angular, capacitor, ionic5, angular12

The `ion-footer` is not showing when my `ion-content` has elements

In this code the footer doesn't appear :

```html
<ion-content>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="text-gray-800 text-3xl font-bold m-0">{{user.name}}</p>
    <p class="text-gray-400 mt-2">{{user['custom:role']}}</p>
  </div>
  <ion-button expand="block" color="primary">logout</ion-button>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

And that works :

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-button expand="block" color="primary" (click)="cognito.logout()">logout</ion-button>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I have tried to remove `div` and `p` tags using `ion-text` or to remove the button and keep only the `p` / `ion-text`

But I cannot make the footer show up with content (except the `ion-button`) in my `ion-content`.

I for the moment use some css, without ion-footer. I'd rather find a non-hacky solution.

Comment: in case there is any CSS specific to your code, you should post it as well.

Comment: The only css the page has, is the hack I did to reproduce the ion-footer behavior. But anyway to reproduce that I think we'd need more than css since it works in some cases.

Comment: Is your app wrapped in <ion-app> tags?

Comment: Yes it is. My app.component.html is a ion-app with ion-router-outlet wrapped in it

Comment: I would recommend creating a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ for quick answer.

Comment: Please check the {{user.name}} & {{user['custom:role']}} data, in case your data like key 'name' will not found so footer will show up with content

Comment: The data are found, and well displayed. Plus I can even change the dynamic data by random text it does the same :/
I guess if no-one experienced that it might be a ionic bug. I'll report it. And keep to my css hack for the moment

Comment: If you inspect the ion-footer element under Developer tools (F12) then you will see that the ion-footer is there but the height is zero or too low so you can't see it but it's there. Adjust it and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the footer not visible problem and are using `IonRouterOutlet` / `ion-router-outlet`, then see the answers here: [ion-content overlaps with ion-header when in ion-router-outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802739)